# Remove Role/Role and Internal subordinates from Manual Sharing button on a record

Tags: lightning, sharing, button

When clicking the **Sharing** lightning button, I am able to see many different options for sharing.

- User
- Portal Role and Subordinates
- Role
- Role and Internal Subordinates
- Role, Internal and Portal Subordinates
- Public Group
- Etc

Is it possible to hide some of the items? I would like to restrict the options to only display User and Public group. I.e. Not allow a user to share a record with a Role, Subordinates or anything else.

Is this possible to configure? How can I tell what drives each individual option in the list?

Thanks!

[image: Image of record Sharing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove Role, Role and Internal subordinates options, as these are  standard salesforce button functionality with [Manual sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.granting_access_to_records_lex.htm&type=5).  Check custom button manual sharing examples here [1](https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2019/02/15/dynamic-record-sharing-manual-sharing-in-lightning-using-flows/) , [2](https://unofficialsf.com/adding-a-manual-sharing-button-to-records-with-lightning-flow/) and see if that helps you.

Thanks